# Automatically convert SSRS report to PDF format

Tags: reporting-services, pdf-generation

Is there a way to have SSRS generating reports in **PDF** format instead of **rdl**?

In addition, is there a way to instruct SSRS to save the generated reports into a specific folder (different from the default)?

Comment: As with programming, where you can't use *objects* instead of *classes*, you can't use PDFs instead of RDLs. The RDL (=Report Definition Language) defines the definition (layout and data sources) of the report. A PDF is what Reporting Services renders when the actual data is fetched and transformed into something visual using the "instructions" in the RDL. In the Report Server Portal, you can save an opened report as PDF (or Word, Excel. CSV etc.). What do you mean saying "default folder"?

Comment: Look into subscriptions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @WolfgangKais, my apologies. I'm completely new on SSRS. Will dig further (starting with the link provided by Alan).

Comment: @AlanSchofield thanks. Will do that.